# How do I ensure that the layout on android studio matches the output on the emulator?

Tags: android

I don't know the answer to the question posted at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=155879.

How do i sort it out please as I was kindly asked to refer this and other questions here?

Answer (score 0):

For one, your emulator is using a Nexus 5 layout, and your preview is using a nexus 4. This is causing the difference

For two, please don't link to external sites with your question, but posting it directly on SO it ensures that others who come in the future will be able to see the question (what happens if the external site goes down, or changes it's link structure)

For three, please make your layout flexible to different screen sizes as you will not be able to control what devices your users will be running your app on. (unless you are only using this app in a controlled environment, and not releasing it to the public)